# Make [jeasyui] a synonym for [jquery-easyui]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[jquery-easyui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-easyui) (318 questions) and [jeasyui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jeasyui) (41 questions) are about the same library: http://www.jeasyui.com/

Quite a few of the questions in these tags are tagged as both, so let's make one a synonym of the other. I suggest making [jeasyui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jeasyui) a synonym for [jquery-easyui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-easyui), because the latter is the more used tag, and in the plugin's documentation, it is referred to as either "jQuery EasyUI" or "EasyUI". [jquery-easyui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-easyui) is the least ambiguous tag as far as I'm concerned.